# Running app with expo go works perfectly but If I build it to an apk crashes at the start all the time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, eas

I'm not sure if someone will be able to help me, since I wasn't able to find anything. I don't understand why because at expo go works perfectly and when I build it, can't even start the app, loads the SplashScreen and closes.
When building with eas build -p android --profile preview.

eas.json:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.7.2"
  },
  "build": {
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "preview2": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      }
    },
    "preview3": {
      "developmentClient": true
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

error at expo.dev website when building the app with this command: eas build -p android --profile preview

```
[stderr] 
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:2087:23: warning: the variable "DebuggerInternal" was not declared in function "__shouldPauseOnThrow"

[stderr] 
        return typeof DebuggerInternal !== 'undefined' && DebuggerInternal.shouldPauseOnThrow === true;

[stderr] 
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr] 
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:9114:7: warning: the variable "setTimeout" was not declared in function "logCapturedError"

[stderr] 
      setTimeout(function () {

[stderr] 
      ^~~~~~~~~~

[stderr] 
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle

[stderr] 
:7079:108: warning: the variable "nativeFabricUIManager" was not declared in function "onChange"

[stderr] 
(fromOrTo = fromOrTo && fromOrTo.stateNode) && fromOrTo.canonical._internalInstanceHandle ? (from && nativeFabricUIManager.setIsJSResponder(from.stateNode.node, false, blockNativeResponder || false), to && nativeFabricUIManager.setIsJSResponder(to.stateNode.node, true, blockNativeResponder || false)) : null !== to ? ReactNativePrivateInterface.UIManager.setJSResponder(to.stateNode.canonical._nativeTag, blockNativeResponder) : ReactNativePrivateInterface.UIManager.clearJSResponder();

[stderr] 
                                                                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr] 
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:7695:21: warning: the variable "clearTimeout" was not declared in anonymous function " 257#"

[stderr] 
    cancelTimeout = clearTimeout;

[stderr] 
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr] 
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:11445:30: warning: the variable "__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__" was not declared in anonymous function " 257#"

[stderr] 
  if ("undefined" !== typeof __REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__) {

[stderr] 
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr] 
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:11744:16:

[stderr] 
warning: the variable "AggregateError" was not declared in function "getAggregateError"

[stderr] 
    if (typeof AggregateError === 'function') {

[stderr] 
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr] 
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:11866:5: warning: the variable "setImmediate" was not declared in function "handleResolved"

[stderr] 
    setImmediate(function () {

[stderr] 
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr] 
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:14740:12: warning: the variable "fetch" was not declared in anonymous function " 453#"

[stderr] 
    fetch: fetch,

[stderr] 
           ^~~~~

[stderr] 
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:14741:14: warning: the variable "Headers" was not declared in anonymous function " 453#"

[stderr] 
    Headers: Headers,

[stderr] 
             ^~~~~~~

[stderr] 
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:14742:14: warning: the variable "Request" was not declared in anonymous function " 453#"

[stderr] 
    Request: Request,

[stderr] 
             ^~~~~~~

[stderr] 
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:14743:15: warning: the variable "Response" was not declared in anonymous function " 453#"

[stderr] 
    Response: Response

[stderr] 
              ^~~~~~~~

[stderr] 
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:14891:24: warning: the variable "FileReader" was not declared in function "readBlobAsArrayBuffer"

[stderr] 
      var reader = new FileReader();

[stderr] 
                       ^~~~~~~~~~

[stderr] 
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:14928

[stderr] 
:36: warning: the variable "Blob" was not declared in anonymous function " 464#"

[stderr] 
        } else if (support.blob && Blob.prototype.isPrototypeOf(body)) {

[stderr] 
                                   ^~~~

[stderr] 
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:14930:40: warning: the variable "FormData" was not declared in anonymous function " 464#"

[stderr] 
        } else if (support.formData && FormData.prototype.isPrototypeOf(body)) {

[stderr] 
                                       ^~~~~~~~

[stderr] 
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:

[stderr] 
14932:44: warning: the variable "URLSearchParams" was not declared in anonymous function " 464#"

[stderr] 
        } else if (support.searchParams && URLSearchParams.prototype.isPrototypeOf(body)) {

[stderr] 
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr] 
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:15159:23: warning: the variable "XMLHttpRequest" was not declared in anonymous function " 473#"

[stderr] 
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

[stderr] 
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr] 
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:14752:76: warning: the variable "self" was not declared in anonymous function " 456#"

[stderr] 
    var global = typeof globalThis !== 'undefined' && globalThis || typeof self !== 'undefined' && self || typeof global !== 'undefined' && global;

[stderr] 
                                                                           ^~~~

[stderr] 
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:

[stderr] 
17487:27: warning: the variable "performance" was not declared in anonymous function " 621#"

[stderr] 
  if ("object" === typeof performance && "function" === typeof performance.now) {

[stderr] 
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr] 
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:17510:26: warning: the variable "navigator" was not declared in anonymous function " 621#"

[stderr] 
  "undefined" !== typeof navigator && undefined !== navigator.scheduling && undefined !== navigator.scheduling.isInputPending && navigator.scheduling.isInputPending.bind(navigator.scheduling);

[stderr] 
                         ^~~~~~~~~

[stderr] 
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:17577:37: warning: the variable "MessageChannel" was not declared in anonymous function " 621#"

[stderr] 
  };else if ("undefined" !== typeof MessageChannel) {

[stderr] 
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr] 
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:27572:34: warning: the variable "requestAnimationFrame" was not declared in function "start 9#"

[stderr] 
this._animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(this.onUpdate.bind(this));

[stderr] 
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

> Task :expo-modules-core:compileReleaseKotlin

> Task :expo-modules-core:buildCMakeRelWithDebInfo[armeabi-v7a]

> Task :app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets

[stderr] 
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:110151:15: warning: the property "color" was set multiple times in the object definition.

[stderr] 
              color: function color() {

[stderr] 
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr] 
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:110144:15: note: The first definition was here.

[stderr] 
              color: function color() {

[stderr] 
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr] 
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:145054:5: warning: the property "elementContainer" was set multiple times in the object definition.

[stderr] 
    elementContainer: {

[stderr] 
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[stderr] 
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:145035:5: note: The first definition was here.

[stderr] 
    elementContainer: {

[stderr] 
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same exact issue, I was using expo-sdk 48 and then downgraded to 47 and it went away. Not sure if it will work for you as well but its worth a shot if you are still blocked.